# How to provide a legally sound license, or "terms of use", for a web application

Tags: web-applications

I am looking for information about providing a license, or "terms of use", for a web application. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use) is very limited, and it seems that unlike "downloadable" software (or perhaps "installable" software, for lack of a better term), for which there is [much more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license), not so much has been written specifically for the licensing of web applications.

Would you say that hiring a lawyer to construct a legally sound "terms of use", or disclaimer, for your web application is absolutely necessary?

Someone asked: Which jurisdiction? My response here is: World-wide. I guess this opens up another topic, i.e. what jurisdictional limits you should take into consideration.

Comment: in which jurisdiction?  Just because it's legally sound in your own jurisdiction doesn't mean it'll be valid anywhere else.

Comment: Is this question a better fit for the "programmers" site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hire a lawyer. Undesirable (and costly) as it seems, it can cost you a helluva lot more to get your TOS wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here are [some UK-centric ones](http://www.website-law.co.uk/documents.html)

Answer (score 1):

Before you hire a lawyer, determine in which country (juristiction) you're web-service lives in. You can state in the ToS, that the laws of country X apply. There's no such thing as 'international internet law', so choose a country.

US law does not specify alot, so you can dictate the terms. EU laws dictate alot more, about what can be put into a ToS. US lawyers do not know very much about EU cosumer protection laws, and vice-versa :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you hoping to cover? Are you worried about your code being stolen or someone doing something stupid on the back of something they see on your site? (Or something else entirely.)

Could you edit to widen what you hope your disclaimer or terms would hope to cover?

Hiring a lawyer might well turn out to be the soundest advice, but the wrong lawyer being asked the wrong questions could end in disaster ...

Comment: My main concern would be getting sued for some reason.